# Put objects on top of each other GridBagLayout

Tags: java

Using GridbagLayout, I am trying to orient a text area under a JFreeChart Chart. However, when I try to do so the two objects are placed side by side instead. Here is how I am approaching the problem:

```
    //Set Gridbag constraints for chart
     GridBagLayout  gridbag3 = new GridBagLayout();

     GridBagConstraints c3 = new GridBagConstraints();      
     c3.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;

     GridBagConstraints c3a = new GridBagConstraints();
     c3a.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;


     gridbag3.setConstraints(chartPanel3,c3);
     gridbag3.setConstraints(scrollPane,c3a);

     tab3.setLayout(gridbag3);
     tab3.add(chartPanel3);
     tab3.add(scrollPane);
```

The dimensions of the objects were defined as:

```
    chartPanel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));


    final JTextArea errorLog = new JTextArea("Error Log:");
    errorLog.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,100));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(errorLog);
    scrollPane.setBounds(10,60,780,500);
```

The view that I'm seeing is the following:
[image]

How can I go about placing this graph on top of this text area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your constraints:  specifically set `gridy` so the scrollpane is placed in a row below the chart.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I am a bit of a beginner at GridBags.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using WindowBuilder for Eclipse. It is really good with this type of stuff.

Comment: I have not. I will definitely check that out though. Thank you for your suggestion.